# Image in Email Signatures

Tags: html, tags, html-email

I'm creating an email signature which has image icons to be displayed. The problem is some people can see the images and but for others, the images are not loaded and show blank box. Here is the code:

```
 <a  style="color: white;" 
 href="https://www.youtube.com/landor" style="text- 
decoration:none"><img  style="color: green; font-size: 6px;   
font-family: Georgia, serif; width: 34px;" 
src="https://dnohehtvi22a2.cloudfront.net/YoutubeIcon.png" 
alt="YouTube"  /> </a></span></p>
```

I read that some email clients block HTML emails images. Do you think this is the only reason? Does anyone know a better way of creating this?

Thank you,

Comment: Is there a specific email client that doesn't display the images?

Comment: You asked about image blocking in some email clients. As Syfer has asked, are you seeing this issue in specific email clients? Outlook desktop programs block images by default and some webmail clients also have the option to block images such as Gmail. So it may be a case of the images not loading until the prompt to download images is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the basics right, i.e., specify a hex value, and use the width and height attribute:

```
<img style="color: #00ff00; font-size: 6px; font-family: Georgia, serif; width: 34px;height:24px;" width="34" height="24" src="https://dnohehtvi22a2.cloudfront.net/YoutubeIcon.png" alt="YouTube" />
```

You can't do anything about Outlook and other email clients that block images by default. There are techniques that try and embed the image, but they still don't get around this image blocking (where the user simply has to click to start the download of images).